# Is it necessary for an email address to exist as a contact before the recipient can be mentioned from within Outlook 2016 and later?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

As of Outlook 2016, it's now possible to mention users by typing the at (@) symbol followed by their name which then automatically adds them to the "To..." section of the email that's being composed. Is it necessary for anybody atted in a message to already exist as a contact within the Contacts folder before they can be mentioned in an email?

Comment: have you tried it to find out ?

Comment: That user should be in your organization. For your reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-mentions-to-get-someone-s-attention-90701709-5dc1-41c7-aa48-b01d4a46e8c7